# Почему накапливается addEvenetListener в хуке useEffect?

Tags: reactjs

*Функционал: ввод текста в input, создание списка путем нажатия enter.*

https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-tereshkova-96pf3?file=/src/App.js

У меня есть два addEventListener. Один вне всяких хуков, другой - в useEffect.

1. Какой логике подчиняется тот, что лежит вне хуков?
2. Почему при нажатии на элемент списка количество кликов удваивается?
3. *Какой чертой* обладает addEventListener, из-за которой он накапливается в хуке useEffect и требует очистки? Почему *console.log(), например, не накапливается?*

Answer (score -1):

я же уже Вам давал ответ!

```
listenerClicks = [];
addEventListener("click", function)
listenerClicks = [
    function
];
addEventListener("click", function)
listenerClicks = [
    function,
    function
];
addEventListener("click", function)
listenerClicks = [
    function,
    function,
    function
];
```

и так далее

При клике происходит проход по массиву listenerClicks и вызов функций. И пока Вы не удалите добавленную туда функцию, до тех пор и будет происходит их вызов при каждом клике.

Почему вызывается несколько раз addEventListener в useEffect? - Потому что у вашем случае useEffect срабатывает первый раз при монтировании компонента, а далее при каждом изменении состояния Вашего todos

Comment: я бы конечно так не сказал, что это дубликат. Вопросы разные. Вопрос здесь заключается в том как рабоатют сами хуки. В таких случаях, когда возникает другой вопрос, я как раз и рекомендую оформлять новым, так как оригинальный может терять актуальность к уже данным ответам. ТС интересуется как они отрабатывают и насколько я понял хочет понять, что, когда и где применять. Вы же совсем не даете ответ по хукам.

Comment: @Dmitry как отрабатывает хук я описал. Почему происходит многократный вызов функций при клике, тоже пояснил

Comment: Хорошо, только в коде присутствуют два использования хука  `useEffect()` и они отличаются, а следуя вашему ответу вообще не очевидно как работает `useEffect`. Я не спорю, субъективное мнение

Comment: но речь в вопросе о том `useEffect`, в котором регистрируется слушатель

Comment: Да, ту часть ответа я понял. Что addEventListener добавляется каждый раз, когда происходит перерисовка компонента. Но это вопрос комплексный. Например, неочевидно, почему обыкновенный console.log() таким же образом не аккумулируется. Чем обладает eventListener и не обладает console.log(), что один накапливается а другой нет? Более того, при нажатии на элемент списка (даже при наличии функции-клинера) щелчок срабатывает два раза, тоже неочевидно, почему. И третий подвопрос, какой логике подчиняется тот слушатель, что не лежит в хуках, а просто находится в компоненте?

Comment: "почему обыкновенный console.log() таким же образом не аккумулируется" - потому-что он просто выполняется выводя данные, а addEventListener регистрирует слушателей (говорит - эй, если будет клик, то выполни пожалуйста эту функцию). А так как этих слушателей нужно хранить до наступления события клика, то они добавляются в массив и вызываются поочереди.
"при нажатии на элемент списка  щелчок срабатывает два раза" - потому-что на момент клика уже два раза отработал addEventListener. А если Вы добавите еще один элемент в список, то, как Вы пишите "щелчок" сработает трижды.

Comment: "какой логике подчиняется тот слушатель, что не лежит в хуках" - никакой разницы в логике нету. Просто код размещенный в хуках с зависимостями выполняется  неоднократно (при изменении состояния зависимостей), а вне хуков и в хуках у которых нету зависимостей - только при создании компонента

Comment: 1) все-таки полагаю, что тот слушатель, который не лежит в хуках, выполняется не только при создании компонента, а при каждой отрисовке; 2) при нажатии на элемент списка щелчок срабатывает два раза всегда вне зависимости от добавления новых элементов в массив, я ведь уже установил removeEventListener

Comment: да, не дописал - При этом код вне хуков будет выполняться и при обновлении компонента

Comment: так а с элементами списка? почему два раза срабатывает

Comment: У Вас есть два useEffect: 
1) первый при создании компонента считывает данные с локалсторадж и обновляет состояние todus (это важно)
2) второй следит за обновлением todus (но и срабатывает при создании компонента)
И у нас выходит, что первый useEffect изменив todus запускает выполнение второго. И т.к. в JS функции выполняются синхронно, то выходит слудующий порядок useEffect1, useEffect2 и снова useEffect2 (запущенный из-за изменения todus в useEffect1)

Comment: @SanyaH Добавьте ваши объяснения в сам ответ, отредактируя его. Я уберу свой минус.

Comment: Почему не работает функция-клинер тогда? В общем, методом экспериментов я обнаружил, что если в консоль выводить e.target, то можно заметить, что щелчок по элементу списка - это щелчок по двум элементам сразу (вложенным). Меняем функцию const handleClick = (e) => console.log("click", e.target); теперь при щелчке на элемент списка имеем в консоли: click 
<span>uikluol</span>
click 
<input type="checkbox"></input>